# Как в PyQt5 использовать одну Dial ручку вместо двух при переключении между двумя radioButton?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qradiobutton, qdial

Основываясь на данном коде мы можем к `radioButton_2` добавить еще одну `daL_2` ручку и слегка изменив код появляется возможность выполнять арифметические операции как левой, так и правой ручкой, в зависимости от выбранного `radioButton`.

Но что, если в проекте таких ручек много? Получается и код большой, и в окне нагромождение.

Возможно ли обойтись одной ручкой вместо двух и получать результаты в зависимости от активированного `radioButton`? Или так делать неправильно?

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

CONFIG_FILE_NAME = 'config.ini'


class New(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(New, self).__init__()
        loadUi("RButton_Dial_save.ui", self)

        self.Exit.clicked.connect(self.close)

        self.dial.setMinimum(0)
        self.dial.setMaximum(10)
        self.dial.setValue(5)

        self.spinbox.setRange(5, 100)
        self.spinbox.setValue(5)

        self.load_settings()

        self.dial.setMinimum(self.spinbox.value() - 5)
        self.dial.setMaximum(self.spinbox.value() + 5)
        self.dial.setValue(self.spinbox.value())
        self.dial.valueChanged.connect(self.dial_changed)

        self.spinbox.valueChanged.connect(self.spinbox_changed)

        self.statusbar = self.statusBar()
        self.statusbar.showMessage('Hello World', msecs=2000)

        self.dial.setValue(self._dial)

        self.radioButton.toggled.connect(self.rb_checked)
        self.spinbox.setEnabled(False)

    def save_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)
        settings.setValue('DialValue', self.dial.value())
        settings.setValue('SpinBoxValue', self.spinbox.value())

    def load_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)

        self.dial.setValue(
            int(settings.value('DialValue', self.spinbox.value())))
        self.spinbox.setValue(
            int(settings.value('SpinBoxValue', self.spinbox.value())))

        self._dial = int(settings.value('DialValue', self.spinbox.value()))

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.save_settings()

    def spinbox_changed(self, value):
        self.dial.setMinimum(value - 5)
        self.dial.setMaximum(value + 5)
        self.dial.setValue(value)

    def dial_changed(self, value):
        self.statusbar.showMessage(f'dial.value = {value}')

    def rb_checked(self, checked):
        if checked:
            self.dial.setEnabled(True)
            self.spinbox.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            self.dial.setEnabled(False)
            self.spinbox.setEnabled(False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))
    window = New()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**RButton_Dial_save.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
    <horstretch>0</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true"/>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <property name="minimumSize">
    <size>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>600</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="maximumSize">
    <size>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>600</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>30</y>
      <width>761</width>
      <height>211</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="title">
     <string>GroupBox</string>
    </property>
    <widget class="QDial" name="dial">
     <property name="enabled">
      <bool>false</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>200</x>
       <y>130</y>
       <width>100</width>
       <height>55</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="wrapping">
      <bool>false</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="notchesVisible">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="Exit">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>650</x>
       <y>30</y>
       <width>93</width>
       <height>28</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Выход</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QSpinBox" name="spinbox">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>300</x>
       <y>20</y>
       <width>111</width>
       <height>22</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QRadioButton" name="radioButton">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>230</x>
       <y>90</y>
       <width>95</width>
       <height>20</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>RButton 1</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QRadioButton" name="radioButton_2">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>420</x>
       <y>90</y>
       <width>95</width>
       <height>20</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>RButton 2</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все возможно, главное вы должны понимать как вы будите взаимодействовать с этим множеством radio кнопок, одной ручкой и при этом выполнять арифметические операции.

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QButtonGroup, \
    QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


CONFIG_FILE_NAME = 'config.ini'


class New(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(New, self).__init__()
        loadUi("RButton_Dial_save.ui", self)

        self.label = QLabel('123 + 123 = ???', self.centralwidget)   # +++
        self.label.move(290, 250)                                    # +++
        self.a, self.b = 0, 0                                        # +++
        
        self.Exit.clicked.connect(self.close)

        self.dial.setMinimum(0)
        self.dial.setMaximum(10)
        self.dial.setValue(5)

        self.spinbox.setRange(5, 100)
        self.spinbox.setValue(5)

        self.load_settings()

        self.dial.setMinimum(self.spinbox.value() - 5)
        self.dial.setMaximum(self.spinbox.value() + 5)
        self.dial.setValue(self.spinbox.value())
        self.dial.valueChanged.connect(self.dial_changed)

        self.spinbox.valueChanged.connect(self.spinbox_changed)

        self.statusbar = self.statusBar()
        self.statusbar.showMessage('Hello World', msecs=2000)

        self.dial.setValue(self._dial)

#        self.radioButton.toggled.connect(self.rb_checked)
#        self.spinbox.setEnabled(False)
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.dial.setEnabled(True)
        self.spinbox.setEnabled(True)
       
        self.buttons = self.radioButton, self.radioButton_2
        self.buttonGroup = QButtonGroup()
        for i, button in enumerate(self.buttons):
            self.buttonGroup.addButton(button, i)
        self.buttonGroup.buttonToggled[int, bool].connect(self.getvalue)
        self.buttons[0].setChecked(True)
        
    def getvalue(self, id, checked):
        #print(f'id = {id}, checked = {checked}') #
        if checked:
            button = self.buttonGroup.button(id)
            #print("{} is checked".format(button.text()))
            if id == 0:
                self.a = self.dial.value()
            elif id == 1:
                self.b = self.dial.value()
            self.label.setText(f'{self.a:>3} + {self.b:>3} = {self.a + self.b:>3}')
            self.label.adjustSize()
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            
    def save_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)
        settings.setValue('DialValue', self.dial.value())
        settings.setValue('SpinBoxValue', self.spinbox.value())

    def load_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)
        self.dial.setValue(
            int(settings.value('DialValue', self.spinbox.value())))
        self.spinbox.setValue(
            int(settings.value('SpinBoxValue', self.spinbox.value())))
        self._dial = int(settings.value('DialValue', self.spinbox.value()))

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.save_settings()

    def spinbox_changed(self, value):
        self.dial.setMinimum(value - 5)
        self.dial.setMaximum(value + 5)
        self.dial.setValue(value)

    def dial_changed(self, value):
        self.statusbar.showMessage(f'dial.value = {value}')
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        if self.radioButton.isChecked():
            self.a = value
        elif self.radioButton_2.isChecked():
            self.b = value
        self.label.setText(f'{self.a:>3} + {self.b:>3} = {self.a + self.b:>3}')
        self.label.adjustSize()        
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        
'''
    def rb_checked(self, checked):
        if checked:
            self.dial.setEnabled(True)
            self.spinbox.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            self.dial.setEnabled(False)
            self.spinbox.setEnabled(False)
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))
    window = New()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Этот вариант тоже очень интересный, беру на заметку. Но я имел ввиду другой. Глядя на изображение теоретически должно быть так: При активации rb A на выходе ручки число 19. При активации rb B на выходе 28.  Переключаясь между rb A и rb B dial.value должен отображать то 19, то 28. Операции суммирования 19 + 28 быть не должно. Приношу извинение за то, что ввел в заблуждение и назвал действие  между входом и выходом ручки арифметической операцией